# How to create a notification pending intent which just brings up the top app activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

Currently I use an `Activity` which finishes immediately, thus pulling the last `Activity` from the app stack.

```
public class ViewlessActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
  }
}
```

Is there any better solution?

UPDATE:

I followed  the recommendation from [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029473/301740) but couldn't make it working like required (it is always showing the MainActivity)

Here the code which creates the pending intent:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingMainActivityIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, mainActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

the `AndroidManifest.xml` sets `android:launchMode="singleTop"`for `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have is fine. You can also just launch your root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) again with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If your app is already running, this will just bring the existing task to the foreground without starting any new `Activity`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to show the last used activity (similar to what task switcher is doing), and with your proposal I would always show the launcher activity, right?!

Comment: No. It brings the task forward as it is, with the last shown `Activity` on top. Just like you want. The only time it will show the launcher `Activity` would be if your app wasn't running at all.

Comment: I guess I m doing something wrong then - it is always showing the main activity in my app. I just updated the question with the code showing how I do it. Any comments highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` which is the first Activity that will be launched when app is opened:

```
if (!isTaskRoot())
{
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Also, remember to use `MainActivity` in `Intent` of `PendingIntent` of Notification.

I hope this might help you.